# Make Javascript instantly/immediately be interchangeable depending on user input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In a js code, i created 3 buttons --- button 1...button 2...button 3
and 3 input fields --- input field 1...input field 2...input field 3

From the beginning of the script all buttons are disabled

button 1 will only be activated (you can click on it) when input field 1 and 2 have numerated values

button 2 will only be activated when input field 1 and 3 have numerated values

button 3 will only be activated when input field 2 and 3 have numerated values.

My problem is when i entered a numerated value for input field 1 and 2, button 1 will not activate (in-clickable) even though it was suppose to

And lets say i redid my code and got my whole code backwards so, at the beginning of my script all the buttons were not disabled (you could click on them). Then i made a simple conditional statement like so

input field 1 = if1
input field 2 - if2

---

```
if (if1.length = 0 || isNaN(if1) && if2.length = 0 || isNaN(if2) ) {
document.getElementById("button 1").disable = true;
}
```

Button 1 will not immediately disable until the user clicks on the button. And if the user were to re-enter the appropriate value type in input field 1, button 1 will not activate (be-clickable) because apparently its permanently disabled.

So down to summary, I'm asking if there is a way to make JavaScript be instantly interactive. Such as a web browser search bar. The moment you type something, you immediately get a list of possible questions and when you don't type anything in them the list disappears and the browser regains its original state.

Any Advice/help shall be greatly appreciated

Due to Life and its problems my code some how got deleted. Thus the lack of code and bunch of words. Sorry.

Comment: its `disabled = true` not `disable=true`.And show more code.

Comment: `if (if1.length = 0)` is not a boolean test -that's an assignment.  You probably want to be use `if (if1.length === 0)`.

Comment: I have given below a more generic solution with attributes than a hard coded version that you accepted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var field1 = document.getElementById('if1');
var field2 = document.getElementById('if2');
var field3 = document.getElementById('if3');

var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var button3 = document.getElementById('button3');


field1.addEventListener('input', function(){
    if(this.value!= '' && field2.value!='')
        button1.disabled = false;
    else
        button1.disabled = true;
  
    if(this.value!= '' && field3.value!='')
        button2.disabled = false;
    else
        button2.disabled = true;
});


field2.addEventListener('input', function(){
    if(this.value!= '' && field1.value!='')
        button1.disabled = false;
    else
        button1.disabled = true;
  
    if(this.value!= '' && field3.value!='')
        button3.disabled = false;
    else
        button3.disabled = true;
  
});


field3.addEventListener('input', function(){
    if(this.value!= '' && field1.value!='')
        button2.disabled = false;
    else
        button2.disabled = true;
  
    if(this.value!= '' && field2.value!='')
        button3.disabled = false;
    else
        button3.disabled = true;
  
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="if1">
<input type="text" id="if2">
<input type="text" id="if3">
<br>
<button type="button" id="button1" disabled="true">Button1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2" disabled="true">Button2</button>
<button type="button" id="button3" disabled="true">Button3</button>
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks m8 this really clears everything up perfectly. Really appreciate it.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

**Generic solution** (*using attributes*)

You can check the answer below which is using `oninput` event and the attributes to handle your situation effectively.

I have added a `data-target` attribute to link the elements together to fit with your requirement.

For an instance, to match the rule `button 1 will only be activated (you can click on it) when input field 1 and 2 have numerated values`, `data-target` of `button1` is id of `textbox 1 & 2`.

Working snippet:

```js
function checkInput() {
  var dataTarget = 'data-target';
  var elm = event.target;
  var targetAttrs = getAttr(elm, dataTarget);
  if(targetAttrs) {
    var targetButtons = targetAttrs.split(',');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < targetButtons.length; i++) {
      var button = document.getElementById(targetButtons[i]);
      targetAttrs = getAttr(button, dataTarget);
      if(targetAttrs) {
        var targetTextBoxes = targetAttrs.split(',');
        var valid = true;
        
        for(var j = 0; j < targetTextBoxes.length; j++) {
          var textBox = document.getElementById(targetTextBoxes[j]);
          if(textBox) {
             valid = isValidNumber(textBox.value);
          }
          
          if(!valid) {
            break;
          }
        }
        
        button.disabled = !valid;
      }
    }
  }
}
     
function isValidNumber(val) {
    return (val && val.length > 0 && !isNaN(val));
}

function getAttr(elm, name){
  var val;
  
  if(elm) {
    var attrs = elm.attributes;
  
    for(var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
      if(attrs[i].name === name) {
         val = attrs[i].value;
         break;
      }
    }
  }
    
  return val;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="textBox1" oninput="checkInput()" data-target="button1,button2" />
</div>
  <br/>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="textBox2" oninput="checkInput()" data-target="button1,button3" />
</div>
  <br/>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="textBox3" oninput="checkInput()" data-target="button2,button3" />
</div>
  <br/>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit" data-target="textBox1,textBox2" disabled />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Submit" data-target="textBox1,textBox3" disabled />
<input type="button" id="button3" value="Submit" data-target="textBox2,textBox3" disabled />
```

**Note**: With this code, when you add more elements, you don't need to change/add any `Javascript` code. Just add the elements and attributes

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it

**Disabling a html button**

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;
```

**Enabling a html button**

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = false;
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SPddm/300/)

**Edited**

Try this...

You apply addEventListener to that DOM object:

```
document.getElementById("IDTeam").addEventListener("change", function() {//call function here});
```

For IE

```
document.getElementById("IDTeam").attachEvent("onchange", function() {//call function here} );
```

Comment: @Jamisco You put the code that does the check into the `onchange` handler of the input fields.

Comment: Yeah exactly
Whenever the input field changes it gets dynamically validated to disable or enable the button